# Is there any evidence that passive investing has real implications for asset prices?

Tags: etf

There is this huge growth in passive investing. If investors are passive, this shouldn't have any implications for the cross-section/time-series of asset prices, i.e. no real economic effects.

Any references?

Answer (score 2):

There is an influential paper by Gormley et al. on this topic called ["Passive investors, not passive owners"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304405X16300319)

Also a new working paper by Heath et al. ["Do index funds monitor?"](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3259433), which used to be called "Passive investors are passive monitors."